# Eslint imports max-len ignorePattern rule

Tags: reactjs, regex, eslint, prettier

Somehow ignoring import files in eslint max-len rule does not  work as expected

```
"max-len": [
      "error",
      {
        "code": 90,
        "ignoreUrls": true,
        "ignorePattern": "^import .*|(\\s*it\\([^)]*\\))"
      }
]
```

It does work for unit test tho, but I must have did something wrong with imports
It does not work for this code:

```
import {CourseMaterialMenu,CourseMaterialHeader,CourseMaterialInfo,CourseMaterialProgress} from "entities/course/course-material";
```

Can you give me a hand with this one?

Comment: Could you post the structure of your package and the content of relevant config/code files? You can also use [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/) to create a [mre].